# NiFi: Get all the processors name involved in a particular run

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a nifi template of 30 processors. There are multiple conditional branches are there in the template. Now, I want to add something at the end of template so that I can get the list of all processors name which has executed for a particular run. 
How can do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just look at the provenance lineage for the given flow file? It will show you graph of events that have happened for the flow file

Answer (score 0):

You could technically insert an `UpdateAttribute` processor after every "operational" processor which would add an attribute containing the most recent processor, but @Bryan is correct that the provenance feature exists to provide this information automatically. If you need to operate on it, you can use the [`SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-site-to-site-reporting-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.reporting.SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask/index.html) to send that data to a *Remote Process Group* (linked to an *Input Port* on the same instance) and then treat that data as any other in NiFi and examine/transform it.